# How smart pointer weak_ptr is bound to shared_ptr in this case?

Tags: c++

Here is an exercise from C++ Primer 5th Edition:

> Exercise 12.20:  Write a program that reads an input file a line at a time into a StrBlob and uses a StrBlobPtr to print each element in that StrBlob.

```
class StrBlob
{
    friend class StrBlobPtr;
public:
    StrBlob(): data(make_shared<vector<string>>()) { }
    StrBlob(initializer_list<string> il): 
        data(make_shared<vector<string>>(il)) { }
    int size() const { return data->size(); }
    bool empty() const { return data->empty(); }
    void push_back(const string& t) { data->push_back(t); }
    void pop_back();

    string& front();
    string& back();

    StrBlobPtr begin();
    StrBlobPtr end();
private:
    shared_ptr<vector<string>> data;
    void check(int i, const string& msg) const;
};

class StrBlobPtr
{
public:
    StrBlobPtr(): curr(0){ }
    StrBlobPtr(StrBlob &a, size_t sz = 0):
            wptr(a.data), curr(sz) { }
    string& deref() const;
    StrBlobPtr& incr();
private:
    shared_ptr<vector<string>> check(size_t i, const string& msg) const;
    weak_ptr<vector<string>> wptr;
    size_t curr;
};

StrBlobPtr StrBlob::begin() 
{
    return StrBlobPtr(*this); 
}

StrBlobPtr StrBlob::end()
{
    return StrBlobPtr(*this, data->size());
}
```

I don't understand in how smart pointer `wptr` is bound to the `data` member of StrBlob in `StrBlobPtr StrBlob::begin` by calling the default constructor function.

While in `StrBlobPtr StrBlob::end()`, `StrBlobPtr(StrBlob &a, size_t sz = 0):wptr(a.data), curr(sz) { }` is called explicitly and `wptr` is bound to `a.data`.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking about. `StrBlob::begin` calls `StrBlobPtr(StrBlob &a, size_t sz = 0)` constructor which initializes wptr as well.

Comment: It looks like the `weak_ptr` is so that when the `StrBlob` is deleted the vector it stores is deleted, even if there are `StrBlobPtr` objects pointing to it.

Comment: As @hynner stated, `StrBlob::begin` doesn't call the default constructor (i.e. the ctor with 0 parameters), it calls the overloaded constructor with a default parameter (`sz` in this case is defaulted to 0); so in the `begin` function `return StrBlobPtr(*this);` is the same as calling `return StrBlobPtr(*this, 0);` .. are you confused on how the member initialization list works so that `wptr(a.data), curr(sz)` "binds" the data to the `weak_ptr` in the overloaded constructor?

Comment: @txtechhelp Yes, I forgot the function of default parameter. I have understand the problem. Thank you .

Comment: @hynner I misunderstood the calling of the default constructor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @tetechhelp answered

> StrBlob::begin doesn't call the default constructor (i.e. the ctor with 0 parameters), it calls the overloaded constructor with a default parameter (sz in this case is defaulted to 0); so in the begin function return StrBlobPtr(*this); is the same as calling return StrBlobPtr(*this, 0);